# What is wrong with my matrix-based backpropagation algorithm?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, linear-algebra, backpropagation

I am working through Nielsen's Neural Networks and Deep Learning. To develop my understanding Nielsen suggests rewriting his back-propagation algorithm to take a matrix based approach (supposedly much quicker due to optimizations in linear algebra libraries).

Currently I get a very low/fluctuating accuracy between 9-10% every single time. Normally, I'd continue working on my understanding, but I have worked this algorithm for the better part of 3 days and I feel like I have a pretty good handle on the math behind backprop. Regardless, I continue to generate mediocre results for accuracy, so any insight would be greatly appreciated!!!

I'm using the MNIST handwritten digits database.

---

### neural_net_batch.py

the neural network functions (backprop in here)

```
"""
neural_net_batch.py

neural_net.py modified to use matrix operations
"""

# Libs
import random
import numpy as np

# Neural Network
class Network(object):
    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)                                                    # Number of layers in network
        self.sizes = sizes                                                              # Number of neurons in each layer
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]                        # Bias vector, 1 bias for each neuron in each layer, except input neurons
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]   # Weight matrix

    # Feed Forward Function
    # Returns netowrk output for input a
    def feedforward(self, a):
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):              # a’ = σ(wa + b)
            a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
        return a

    # Stochastic Gradient Descent
    def SGD(self, training_set, epochs, m, eta, test_data):
        if test_data: n_test = len(test_data)
        n = len(training_set)

        # Epoch loop
        for j in range(epochs):

            # Shuffle training data & parcel out mini batches
            random.shuffle(training_set)
            mini_batches = [training_set[k:k+m] for k in range(0, n, m)]

            # Pass mini batches one by one to be updated
            for mini_batch in mini_batches:
                self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)

            # End of Epoch (optional epoch testing)
            if test_data:
                evaluation = self.evaluate(test_data)
                print("Epoch %6i: %5i / %5i" % (j, evaluation, n_test))
            else:
                print("Epoch %5i complete" % (j))


    # Update Mini Batch (Matrix approach)
    def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
        m = len(mini_batch)
        nabla_b = []
        nabla_w = []

        # Build activation & answer matrices
        x = np.asarray([_x.ravel() for _x,_y in mini_batch])    # 10x784 where each row is an input vector
        y = np.asarray([_y.ravel() for _x,_y in mini_batch])    # 10x10 where each row is an desired output vector

        nabla_b, nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)      # Feed matrices into backpropagation

        # Train Biases & weights
        self.biases = [b-(eta/m)*nb for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]
        self.weights = [w-(eta/m)*nw for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]


    def backprop(self, x, y):
        # Gradient arrays
        nabla_b = [0 for i in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [0 for i in self.weights]
        w = self.weights

        # Vars
        m = len(x)      # Mini batch size
        a = x           # Activation matrix temp variable
        a_s = [x]       # Activation matrix record
        z_s = []        # Weighted Activation matrix record
        special_b = []  # Special bias matrix to facilitate matrix operations

        # Build special bias matrix (repeating biases for each example)
        for j in range(len(self.biases)):
            special_b.append([])
            for k in range(m):
                special_b[j].append(self.biases[j].flatten())
            special_b[j] = np.asarray(special_b[j])

        # Forward pass
        # Starting at the input layer move through each layer
        for l in range(len(self.sizes)-1):
            z = a @ w[l].transpose() + special_b[l]
            z_s.append(z)
            a = sigmoid(z)
            a_s.append(a)

        # Backward pass
        delta = cost_derivative(a_s[-1], y) * sigmoid_prime(z_s[-1])
        nabla_b[-1] = delta
        nabla_w[-1] = delta @ a_s[-2]
        for n in range(2, self.num_layers):
            z = z_s[-n]
            sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
            delta = self.weights[-n+1].transpose() @ delta * sp.transpose()
            nabla_b[-n] = delta
            nabla_w[-n] = delta @ a_s[-n-1]

        # Create bias vectors by summing bias columns elementwise
        for i in range(len(nabla_b)):
            temp = []
            for j in nabla_b[i]:
                temp.append(sum(j))
            nabla_b[i] = np.asarray(temp).reshape(-1,1)

        return [nabla_b, nabla_w]

    def evaluate(self, test_data):
        test_results = [(np.argmax(self.feedforward(t[0])), t[1]) for t in test_data]
        return sum(int(x==y) for (x, y) in test_results)

# Cost Derivative Function
# Returns the vector of partial derivatives C_x, a for the output activations y
def cost_derivative(output_activations, y):
    return(output_activations-y)

# Sigmoid Function
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

# Sigmoid Prime (Derivative) Function
def sigmoid_prime(z):
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))
```

### MNIST_TEST.py

test script

```
import mnist_data
import neural_net_batch as nn

# Data Sets
training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_data.load_data_wrapper()

training_data = list(training_data)
validation_data = list(validation_data)
test_data = list(test_data)

# Network
net = nn.Network([784, 30, 10])

# Perform Stochastic Gradient Descent using MNIST training & test data,
# 30 epochs, mini_batch size of 10, and learning rate of 3.0
net.SGD(list(training_data), 30, 10, 3.0, test_data=test_data)
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist not so sure; from their own [on-topic](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) re implementation questions like this one: "*As a rule of thumb, if you can describe your problem without the source code and if you think that a solution to your problem can be given without the source code, then your question is on-topic*". Even [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "*f you have a programming or implementation question that can be answered without reference to data, it is better suited for Stack Overflow*".

Answer (score 1):

A very helpful Reddit (u/xdaimon) helped me to get the following answer ([on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MLQuestions/comments/fzlzn2/whats_wrong_with_my_matrixbased_backpropagation/fn5f5ud/)):

> Your backward pass should be
>
> ```
>     # Backward pass
>     delta = cost_derivative(a_s[-1], y) * sigmoid_prime(z_s[-1])
>     nabla_b[-1] = delta.T
>     nabla_w[-1] = delta.T @ a_s[-2]
>     for n in range(2, self.num_layers):
>         z = z_s[-n]
>         sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
>         delta = delta @ self.weights[-n+1] * sp
>         nabla_b[-n] = delta.T
>         nabla_w[-n] = delta.T @ a_s[-n-1]
> ```
>
> One way to find this bug is to remember that there should be a
>   transpose somewhere in the product that computes nabla_w.
>
> And if you're interested, the transpose shows up in the matrix
>   implementation of backprop because AB is the same as the sum of outer
>   products of the columns of A and the rows of B. In this case A=delta.T
>   and B=a_s[-n-1] and so the outer products are between the rows of
>   delta and the rows of a_s[-n-1]. Each term in the sum is nabla_w for a
>   single element in the batch which is exactly what we want. If the
>   minibatch size is 1 you can easily see that delta.T@a_s[-n-1] is just
>   the outer product of the delta vector and activation vector.

Testing shows not only is the network accurate again, the expected speedup is present.

Comment: Helped you *forget*? And is this an answer, or what (not at all clear)?

Comment: Thank you, I meant to say "to get".  What is unclear about the answer? Not only does it go into how to fix the code, it also explains how to reach the correct understanding regarding the nabla w calculation. If you test the code with those small changes you can see the results that are mentioned.

Comment: OK. SInce you apparently quote someone else (you have even included the part in quotes, which practically lost in the big picture), it would me more proper to also include the actual link.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still getting used to the etiquette on stack overflow. I've included the link to his answer as well.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I disagree only because it was very difficult to find any questions/answers on the subject. It was practically impossible to find the implementation of backprop I was looking for. I thought it would be useful to post the answer I did get here as well, for anyone looking in the future this is more visible/formal than a post buried in the linear algebra subreddit. Also pretty knew to SO so I'm not sure on all the rules.